# DT decimal time to clock time conversion

Tags: r, time, shiny, dt

I'm using DT in shiny to display decimal time currently.

Example here:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

  # server-side processing

  base<-as.POSIXct('2000-01-01 00:00:00 EST')

  mtcars2 = mtcars[, 5:6]
  mtcars2 %<>% 
    mutate(drat = base+(3600*drat),
           wt = base+(3600*wt))

    DT::datatable(mtcars2,
        extensions = 'Buttons',
        options = list(
          scrollX = TRUE,
          scrollY = TRUE,
          pageLength = 10,
          dom = 'Blfrtip',
          buttons = c('copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print')
        )
  ) %>% 
  formatDate( 1:2,method = 'toLocaleString', params = list('en-US',year = NULL))
```

I've been looking into using `toTimeString` or similar methods from the `formatDate()` section of [DT's functions](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/functions.html). How can I go about converting this from decimal time "2.3" hrs into "2:18"? I did find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38875173/date-format-change-with-dt-and-shiny)
after which I have upgraded DT to the latest dev version and included `params=` but have been unsuccessful in finding the necessary combination to select for just HH:MM.

Comment: i only see `01:00:00 GMT+0100`,..

Comment: Edited to reflect correct time values, I just need to select for only the HH:MM now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can achieve it via `formatDate()`, because I don't see any date conversion method in JavaScript that supports the suppression of any time components. For example, if you read [the documentation of `toLocalString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString), you can see that the only possible values for the `year` component are `numeric` and `2-digit`, and you cannot set it to `null` to suppress it.

The most straightforward way to display your date/time data in the `HH:MM` format is to format the data properly before passing it to `DT::datatable()`, e.g., using the R function `format(..., '%H:%M')`.

I think it is possible to achieve your goal by providing a row or column callback function in JavaScript, but it will be a little bit complicated.

Comment: Really appreciate it, Yihui. Confirming that `format(..., '%H:%M')` is the best solution as long as time values remain under 24 hours.